# obtener documento dentro de codigo html

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scraping

estoy intentando obtener las url de los anuncios que aparecen en las búsquedas que se realizan en esta url
'https://www.internetcorkboard.com/ar?q=brain+stem+injuries'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver.get('https://www.internetcorkboard.com/ar?q=brain+stem+injuries')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html')
```

, el problema es que hay un documento html dentro del page_source de la página, que es donde se almacena las url que me interesan

¿alguien sabe como acceder al documento y que se pueda scrapear?

Answer (score 0):

He probado a obtener los *links* directamente y a partir de ellos extraer su *atributo href*, pero por algún motivo que desconozco no funciona para los *links* de los anuncios.

He tenido éxito obteniendo el *elemento padre* que contiene el *link anuncio*:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('PartialSearchResults-item-title')
```

La lista `elements` es una lista de elementos `<div>`, cada uno de ellos contiene un elemento `<a>` cuyo *atributo href* es el link del anuncio.

Puedes iterar sobre cada uno de los elementos para encontrar el `<a>` que te interesa, y a partir de este obtener el *atributo href*:

```
for element in elements:
    links = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

    for link in links:
        url = link.get_attribute('href')
```

**En resumen:**

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(f'https://www.internetcorkboard.com/web?qo=semQuery&ad=semA&q=brain%20stem%20injuries&o=100081&ag=fw&an=google_s')


elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('PartialSearchResults-item-title')
urls = []

for element in elements:
    links = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    # links es una lista de un solo elemento
    # por lo que a continuación utilizo un bucle
    # pero podrías declarar link = links[0] y continuar sin el siguiente bucle

    for link in links:
        url = link.get_attribute('href')
        urls.append(url)

for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

Comment: El problemas está en que las url de los anuncios no se capturan, por lo que he estado viendo creo que es un ```iframe``` pero no estoy del todo seguro, si cambio al iframe no puedo capturar ningún dato

Comment: Llevas razón, no se capturan los links de los anuncios. He modificado la respuesta, echa un vistazo! si entendí bien la pregunta funciona. Un saludo.